# PushSharp stopped working

Tags: c#, ios, pushsharp

After using PushSharp for quite a while came across the problem - on sending APNS push I am  receiving this message:

> Failure: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> The maximum number of
>   Send attempts to send the notification was reached! ->
>   {"aps":{"alert":"Hello","badge":1,"sound":"sound.caf","content-available":1},"JobFetch":"Start"}
>   Channel Exception: PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService ->
>   System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party
>   has closed the transport stream.

I did checked and re-issued all the certificates (Development and SSL) and that doesn't help.
Any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/139

Comment: Thanks, I'll post an issue there too